# AAPT: error: '6495ed' is incompatible with attribute background (attr) reference|color

Tags: java, android-studio

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="6495ed"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code and it keeps displaying  the error incompatible with attribute background

Answer (score 0):

`android:background="6495ed"` is the problem. You want it written as `android:background="#6495ed"`

A better practice is to save those color values in an XML file that specifically holds colors. These go in your res>values folder, under colors.xml.

To do it that way, in res>values>colors.xml, add:

`<color name="addala_color_blue">#6495ed</color>`

Then in your layout XML, you'd set:

`android:background="@color/addala_color_blue"` or whatever you named it.

Comment: `cornflowerblue` is #6495ed.